# MATLAB class for loading files

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

Beginner with MATLAB here. I'm trying to write a class that will load in images from a folder, and here's what I have:

```
classdef ImageLoader
    %IMAGELOADER Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        currentImage = 0;
        filenames={};
        filenamesSorted={};
    end

    methods
        function imageLoader = ImageLoader(FolderDir)
            path = dir(FolderDir);
            imageLoader.filenames = {path.name};
            imageLoader.filenames = sort(imageLoader.filenames);
        end

        function image = CurrentImage(this)
            image = imread(this.filenames{this.currentImage});
        end

        function image = NextImage(this)
            this.currentImage = this.currentImage + 1;
            image = imread(this.filenames{this.currentImage});
        end
    end    
end
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
i = ImageLoader('football//Frame*');
image=i.NextImage;

imshow(image);
```

The files are named Frame0000.jpg, Frame0001.jpg ... etc.
I want the constructor to load in all the file names so that I can then retrieve the next file simply by calling `i.NextImage`, but I can't get it working.

---

Got it working.

class:

```
classdef ImageLoader
    %IMAGELOADER Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties(SetAccess = private)
        currentImage
        filenames
        path
        filenamesSorted;
    end

    methods
        function imageLoader = ImageLoader(Path,FileName)
            imageLoader.path = Path;
            temp = dir(strcat(Path,FileName));
            imageLoader.filenames = {temp.name};
            imageLoader.filenames = sort(imageLoader.filenames);
            imageLoader.currentImage = 0;
        end

        function image = CurrentImage(this)
            image = imread(this.filenames{this.currentImage});
        end

        function [this image] = NextImage(this)
            this.currentImage = this.currentImage + 1;
            image = imread(strcat(this.path,this.filenames{this.currentImage}));
        end
    end    
end
```

call:

```
i = ImageLoader('football//','Frame*');
[i image]=i.NextImage;

imshow(image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you  can't change the state of an object (as you do when *incrementing* the `currentimage` pointer) without explicitly updating the value of the object itself at the end. AFAIK every function call passes objects byval, that means that `NextImage` just modifies a local copy of `this` (which is not a pointer/reference to the current object, rather a copy).

Thus, what you can do is writing your method as

```
  function [this image] = NextImage(this)
        this.currentImage = this.currentImage + 1;
        image = imread(this.filenames{this.currentImage});
  end
```

and call it as

```
 [i image]=i.NextImage;
```

Comment: Note that you can achieve this behavior without using explicit pass-back of the object using handle objects.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html  Though I find these incredibly tricky to use since even though the behavior of these objects is radically different from the behavior of all other MATLAB variables, the syntax is identical

Comment: @Pete, thank you very much for this information! Indeed I see huge overhead in the code I posted; handles, giving java-like references, can definitely fix it.